# How to manage node_modules in Continous deployment via jenkins?

Tags: node.js, jenkins, node-modules, continuous-deployment

Trying to develop node.js application since it is under development requires lot of deployments to be done to production environment.During every releases do we have to move entire node_modules to production ?

Note : production environment is restricted from internet access so cannot use NPM install there.

Comment: Moving `node_modules` is not a good idea. Certain packages depends on the OS libraries and hence they are built during npm install. So moving node_modules is out of question if the OS differs and even if there are some libraries not matching could cause an issue.

Comment: I have the exact requirement. Have you found any solution? I am trying to achieve the same using symlink.

Answer (score 0):

You should check out [npmrc](https://docs.npmjs.com/configuring-npm/npmrc.html) file, which, among other things, decides source of all your node modules.

Your production server should have such file in its project root, and it must store the location of your npm packages that must be installed.

The registry value inside `npmrc` file is where you can put your packages. You can read [more about it here](https://nodesource.com/blog/configuring-your-npmrc-for-an-optimal-node-js-environment).

Comment: Please explain by steps